# How do I Loop Through Excel Pivot Table's Secondary (Child) Fields?

Tags: vba, excel, treeview, pivot-table

My ultimate goal is to populate a form TreeView with my pivot table results, which means I will have parent nodes and children nodes.

Let's say I have the following pivot table results (from a table)

```
FirstNames

[+] Bill
[+] Bob
[-] Charles
      Charles Jameson
      Charles Johnson
      Charles Smith
[+] James
[+] Zachary
```

When I loop through `myPivotTable.PivotFields("FirstNames").PivotItems`, I loop through "Bill", "Bob", "Charles", "James", "Zachary".  This gives me my parent nodes, but I also want my children nodes `(e.g. "Charles Jameson", "Charles Johnson", and "Charles Smith").`

How can I loop through child fields?

Answer (score 1):

The child nodes have their own names that are not necessarily considered "child nodes", they're peers.  So you just change the "PivotFields("FirstNames")" portion to get these.  But I suppose you want them in context with how they are associated as a result of the pivot.

It might be easier to interact with the data in the way that you need it, instead of relying on the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
For Each pvtField in myPivotTable.PivotFields("FirstNames").PivotItems
```

You should just be able to use

```
For Each pvtField in myPivotTable.PivotFields("FirstNames").PivotItems
    If pvtField.Orientation = xlRowField Then
       For Each pvtField2 in myPivotTable.PivotFields(pvtField.Name).PivotItems
```